# Repairing a GE stackable washer and dryer damaged by an unbalanced load

Tags: dryer, washing-machine

My GE stackable washer and dryer combo stopped working after I pressed the button because of a loud noise. The load was not balanced. Now the washing, spinning rinse and lid lights are flashing. The start button is stuck and fabric softener button is on too. The technician is not sure what the problem is but has asked us to order door latch lid lock. The dryer is still working.

The model number is: gtup27oem1ww.

I do not want to purchase this part if it not necessary. Can someone assist with diagnosing the problem?

Comment: Find the key that says "caps lock", press it once and then never ever touch that key again.

Comment: If you are paying the technician, he should be the one ordering parts and taking the risk whether that is the problem.  Some on-line appliance parts companies will accept returns if returned in like-new condition; verify before ordering.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a suitable answer [here](http://www.applianceblog.com/mainforums/threads/30564-Stacked-GE-washer-dryer-lights-Blinking-doeent-start-at-all) which says:

- Check the wires going to the lid open switch to see if they are disconnected or severed, which apparently happened from an excessively unbalanced load.
- If so, reconnect the wires and reset the washer logic by turning the cycle control knob to the 4 o'clock position, press and hold the start/pause button until the light blinks (3-5 seconds wait).  Then, while holding in the start/pause button, turn knob to the 6 o'clock position (blinking light should stop).